# How to identify and element when the id, Xpath values are changing dynamically in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dynamic, element

other buttons on the page has same elements except the numeric part in the id.

**COMMUNICATE**

I tried below xpath to locate the element but it did not work. Got below error
 stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
Can any one please help me to write code for clicking this button

Comment: Could you share some details about what code you have tried and html for the relevant control?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the xpath with "contains", if it's changing some part of the id.

But stale element reference is something different. It means that the element you're trying to interact, is changed after you create a webelement reference (like refresh etc.). Can you give a url, if it's public?